# Annotation Not Selectable in 3D Navigation (Until Zoomed Out) - Android

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

My annotations are not clickable in 3D map mode during navigation. However, if I zoom out to a certain level, "onAnnotationSelected" is being called. This is not the case in 2D mode.

I saw in iOS documentation that there is an annotationTapZoomLimit property, but I cannot find it in Android. How can I make annotation selectable in 3D navigation mode?

Comment: I have been having the same issue. Have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.